# Timeout in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am testing a set of Cloud Functions locally and have emulators for Database, Firestore, Hosting, PubSub and Functions setup as required. I am trying to do the following:

1. In the `functions/index.js` file, I am importing modules that are used as HTTP trigger for different endpoints.
2. I am using Dependency Injection (DI) for allowing the modules to access all common dependencies from the `functions/index.js` file.

My approach in code so far:

functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const firestoreSession = require('connect-session-firebase')(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const ref = admin.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credential: admin.credential.cert('path/to/credential.js')
});

// services
const UserService = require('./user/index')({
    express, cookieParser, cors, ref,
    session, firestoreSession, validationResult
});

exports.user = functions.https.onRequest(UserService);
```

The HTTP request triggers are instances of express. I am injecting the dependencies (as in UserService) and then exposing the trigger under the URL BASE_URL/user. There are few other services like this. Inside the UserService, I have the following:

```
module.exports = function({
    express, cors,
    session, firestoreSession,
    cookieParser, validationResult, ref
}) {
    const Validators = require('./validators');

    const userserv = express();
    userserv.use(cors({ origin: true }));
    userserv.use(session({
        name: 'user_session',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        secret: 'TOKEN_SECRET_HERE',
        store: new firestoreSession({
            database: ref.database()
        })
    }));

    userserv.post('/login', (req, res, nxt) => {
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            message: 'Logged In'
        });
    });
    // ... other route handlers
    return userserv;
};
```

functions/user/index.js

Now when I start the emulators, everything starts fine. When I send a POST request using curl, the function just freezes until a timeout occurs. Here's a sample of the curl request:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{}' http://localhost:5001/<App>/<region>/user/login
```

When the timeout occurs or when I manually stop the emulators, I see the JSON response as expected. Not sure what's causing the function to freeze. My guess would be something related to the database setup for the session store that's causing the function to enter an infinite loop of requests. Some suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using DI because I want to manage the imports in one file and also share the session store among the services. The way I have seen to setup firebase session store uses the app ref from `admin.initializeApp` and so, it would be easy to pass that as an argument to the all the imported service modules.

**Update 1**

The problem is definitely with the session middleware. Commenting out the session setup code in `functions/user/index.js` doesn't cause the server to freeze when the request is made and a response is sent promptly as expected.

**Update 2**
After looking at the debug logs, this is what seemed "problematic" from the `database-debug.log`:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/home/zerocool/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.3.1.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Add some debug logging to find out exactly how far your function gets.  Right now, you're not giving yourself any indications.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated the question with output from debug log. Also, the problem is with session setup as commenting it out solves the issue.

Comment: If this works when deployed but not on the emulator, post an issue on Firebase CLI GitHub with the instructions on how to build a complete, minimal example that doesn't work the way you expect.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation enough to comment.

Did you setup the key?

```
const ref = firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert('path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json'),
  databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com'
});
```

Also, try to pass the flags: **resave and saveUninitialized**

```
express()
  .use(session({
    store: new FirebaseStore({
      database: ref.database()
    }),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge : 60000,
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: false }
  }));
```

Check the security:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "false",
    ".write": "false",
    "sessions": {
      ".read": "false",
      ".write": "false"
    },
    "some_public_data": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

Start CORS with those flags:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    if(req.session){
      res.header("mytoken",req.token);
    }
    next();
});
```

EDIT 1: Sending the post inside cors

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

userserv.post('/login', (req, res) => {    
     cors(req, res, () => {

      console.log('Sending POST inside CORS')

      res.status(200).send({message: 'Logged In'})

    });            
 });
```

Comment: Can you explain why is it needed to add "token" on the res header inside the cors middleware? And as you can see, I have not setup any session yet. The basic code should just return the JSON response. I added the credentials though and it didn't change anything. As for cookie, I need it to be secure and http only as well. For local environment, I can set secure to false but not on production. And http only is a necessity in my case. The database rules are also there as you described.

Comment: You don't need the 'token', it's just security stuff for http auth. My guess it's cors are blocking your post request. Do you have some message on browser console?

Comment: Thanks for your help but the issue was not CORS related. As you can see from the updates on my post, it was an issue with the real time database setup. I actually deployed the function and tested with the production database URL and it worked; the sessions were also created as expected. This clearly means I am setting up the database wrongly in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was finally able to run the functions and get the expected result as expected. As identified in the updates to the original post, the issue was with `connect-session-firebase` store setup. For setting up locally, I tried the following:

```
// ... other code unchanged
const ref = admin.initializeApp({
    // remove the following line
    // databaseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credential: admin.credential.cert('path/to/credential.js')
});
```

Also, as per the documentation for `connect-session-firebase`, I need to setup a `.env` file with the following:

```
FIREBASE_DATBASE_URL=http://localhost:9090
FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=./serviceAccount.json
```

The database was running properly and a query for the `sessions.json` file yielded an entry as expected. Also tested this after deployment (for that, I did not require the .env file and had to change the databaseURL to the actual database URL for the project). Thanks everyone for their time and help.